# Как запустить несколько итераций одного цикла for параллельно (асинхронно)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, asyncio

Парсю данные с википедии, что занимает неприемлемое время. Хочу сделать вместо одного потока, хотя бы 5. После гугления нашел варианты с асинхронностью, а точнее 2 варианта:

1. Запускать асинхронно функцию (async def func_name)
2. Запускать асинхронно цикл (async for)

Ниже привел "порезанный" код, чтоб показать последовательность обработки данных (привел комментарии, чтоб быстро понять, о чем код).

```
def update_data(region_id=None, country__inst=None, upper_region__inst=None):
    all_ids = []

    # Получаем данные по странам или регионам или субрегионам страны
    countries_or_regions_dict = OSM().get_countries_or_regions(region_id)

    # Запускаем цикл по обработке полученных данных
    for osm_id in countries_or_regions_dict:
        names = countries_or_regions_dict[osm_id]['names']

         if 'wiki_uri' in countries_or_regions_dict[osm_id]:
            wiki_uri = countries_or_regions_dict[osm_id]['wiki_uri']

            # ПАРСЕР: Грузит с Википедии переводы стран или регионов или субрегионов
            translated_names = Wiki().get_translations(wiki_uri, osm_id)

            if not region_id:  # Для стран
                country__inst = Countries.objects.update_or_create(osm_id=osm_id,
                                                                   defaults={**countries_regions_dict[osm_id]})[0]

            else: # Для регионов (рекурсия)
                upper_region__inst = Regions.objects.update_or_create(osm_id=osm_id,
                                                                      country=country__inst,
                                                                      region=upper_region__inst,
                                                                      defaults={**countries_regions_dict[osm_id]})[0]
            # Добавляем в БД переводы названий с википедии
            for lang_code in names:
                ###

            # РЕКУРСИЯ: Если есть у страны регионы или у регионов субрегионы, запускаем рекурсию
            if 'divisions' in countries_or_regions_dict[osm_id]:
                regions_list = countries_or_regions_dict[osm_id]['divisions']

                for division_id in regions_list:
                    all_regions_osm_ids = update_osm(region_id=division_id, country__inst=country__inst,
                                                              upper_region__inst=upper_region__inst)

                    all_ids += all_regions_osm_ids

    return all_ids
```

Хочу сделать через вариант с `async for`. К сожалению, примеры, которые я видел в интернете, не позволили мне понять принцип организации кода.

Я понял, что нужно `def update_data` поменять на `async def update_data` и соответственно `for osm_id in countries_or_regions_dict` -> `async for osm_id in countries_or_regions_dict`,

но также не смог найти информацию, нужно ли и если "да", то где?, использовать `get_event_loop()` для цикла, и как\где указать, сколько итераций цикла могут быть одновременно запущены?

Comment: Может, стоит обратить внимание на `multiprocessing.Process`? Работает он достаточно просто:
`p = Process(target=ваша_функция)`
`p.start()`

Comment: @iliaznk Если запустить функцию исходя из вашего предложения, каждая из запущенных функций будет генерировать одинаковый цикл (получим 2+ параллельных цикла). Таким образом один цикл ничего не знает о работе другого(-их) цикла(-ов) и получается обработка одних и тех же данных несколько раз. Мне же нужно запустить следующую итерацию цикла до окончания предыдущей итерации, т.е чтоб генерировался один цикл и несколько итераций этого цикла запускались параллельно. Если я чтото не так понимаю, прошу просветить)

Comment: multiprocessing.Pool().map() работает в разы быстрее ручного запуска процессов, а функция map разделит куски  данных между процессами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные сложны в вычислениях, то используйте [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).

Для простых блокирующих вычислений удобней будет [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor), так как он не несет бремя синхронизации и пересылки данных между процессами. Совместно с асинхронным вэб-клиентом (нужно переписать ваши парсеры) это будет хороший вариант.

Функция map у этих пулов отлично подходит для обработки масивов.